# How to get the data to update using UseState?

Tags: arrays, typescript, react-native, use-state

I having been trying to update the data using UseState with Typescript. The data is never updated what so ever. I am not sure what is it that I am missing. I just want to make sure that the information from local mock data that accepts those 5 properties and be send or updated to the store data. But whenever the button is pressed I am still get the same information that's already there and the mock data was never imported in. Help me if there's something I am missing or something I may need to change. Thank you, and let me know if you need any more informations.

```
import verification from '../mock-api/sample/TripVerificationSample.json';

interface VerificationTripProps {
  isVisible: boolean;
  style?: {};
  onModalBack: () => void;
  onPress: () => void;
  data?: Reservation[];
}

const TripVerificationModal: React.FC<VerificationTripProps> = ({
  isVisible = false,
  onModalBack,
  onPress,
  data,
}) => {
  console.log('before data is pushed ' + JSON.stringify(data));
  const [updateData, setUpdateData] = useState<Reservation[]>([]);
  const LoadConfirmInfo = () => {
    //set old array to add new array
    setUpdateData(previous => [
    ...previous,
    {
      confirmNumber: verification.confirmNumber,
      startDate: new Date(verification.startDate),
      endDate: new Date(verification.endDate),
      hotel: verification.hotel,
      status: ReservationStatusType.Upcoming,
    },
    ]);
    console.log('checking if info is pushed ' + JSON.stringify(updateData));
  };

  return (
    <View>
      <BackBaseModal
        isVisible={isVisible}
        onModalBack={onModalBack}
        modalText={tripVerification.headerText}
        subText={tripVerification.subText}
        buttonText={tripVerification.confirmBtn}
        onPress={() => {
          onPress();
          LoadConfirmInfo();
        }}>
</View>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not guaranteed that the `state` is directly updated since `setState` is an async function! By directly logging the state after setting it, will most likely log the old value.

However, setting a new state causes a rerender, thus it is guaranteed that the new value is available in the next render cycle. This can be validated by using a `useEffect` with the states value as a dependency.

```js
useEffect(() => {
   console.log(updateData)}
, [updateData])
```

Comment: I am getting a return of no data what so ever. When I added the useEffect, I check the log and I still got a return of nothing. I am assuming is because the value 'data' is not been used anywhere, however if I were to put that any where lets just say in the useState, I will get an error. Is there another approach to this or am I missing something to fix this problem?

Comment: Have you logged ‘verification’?

Comment: Yes I have logged 'verfication' which is the mock data, and also logged the 'data' which is the store data. I just want to send the 5 properties of verification data to the store data 'data'. But nothing seems to work or doing anything.